# Jquery mobile external panel not opening on windows phone

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

I am developing mobile application using phonegap. When I deploy my code in Windows 8 mobile phone my external panel is not opening. It shows a blank page when I try to open it.

My code is:

```
<div data-role="page" id="more" data-title="Sho Sho Restaurant">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">&nbsp;</h1>
            <a class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" href="#mypannel"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            //App content here
        </div>
    </div>

<div data-role="panel" id="mypannel" data-position="left" data-theme="c" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay">
        <ul class="ui-content" data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
            <li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
//Other menu lists here.
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a stack trace available, please post it.  That would help narrow down the reason this is happening.

My guess is that you are not initializing the ***external*** panel.  Items inside the page element will be automatically initialized for you when the page is created.  External elements (jqm elements like popups or menus that can be outside the page) must be setup for you can use them. For an external panel:

```
$( "#mypannel" ).panel(options);
```

Where options can be found in the [api documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/).  Also, check out the [demos page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external/).

Depending on your application structure, you could move the panel inside the page to have it automatically initialized when the page is created.